# Detect clicks in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to detect clicks on a gameobject in Unity but I can't even get the simplest thing to work. I tried everything but can't get it to detect the clicks. Here is my structure:

[image]

Canvas settings:

[image]

Gameobject settings:

[image]

Underlying canvas settings:

[image]

**What I have tried**

1. Disabled Graphics Raycaster on underlying canvas.
2. Using Layer Default on all.
3. Having Is Trigger either on or off on the collider on the gameobject.
4. Any combination of the above.
5. Using OnMouseDown to detect clicks.
6. Using raycasting in the update function:

   ```
    private void Update()
    {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePosition, Vector2.zero);

        if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject == gameObject)
        {
            Debug.Log("Clicked on the GameObject.");
            popupWindow.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
   ```

   }

**How do I get it to detect clicks on the collider?**

Answer (score 1):

2D Rays are in the xy plane, z does not exist here.
Therefore you cannot send a ray "through" the screen.

Instead of using raycasts, you can utilize the `IPointer` interfaces.  These are found in the `UnityEngine.EventSystems` namespace.

Here is a simple example using the click handler.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Click2D : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Clicked {name}");
    }
}
```

You can incorporate this into your existing `Building` script or use it as a standalone script.

Comment: I solved it by making it a button insted for now. But with your method, how can I know that I click on just the collider and not the building itself? I can check for the type of thing I hit?
And technically there is a z-plane since things are rendered on top of eachother :)

Comment: You posted another question where I answered how to detect the click on a specific collider.  When I mentioned there is no z axis, I was referring to 2D raycasts which are in the xy plane